# How to include python compiler dependencies in maven web project?

Tags: python, maven-2, buildpath

I have a simple website that has some related python scripts that I use for maintenance of that website (note, the python code are util scripts that we execute manually for various tasks).  I need to be able to share it with other developers who may want to edit it.

What Maven dependencies do I need to include so that the python compiler is included at runtime and can be put on the build path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood the question but [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) includes a compiler:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.python</groupId>
    <artifactId>jython</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You got it.  I was looking for a compiler that could be run as part of a maven compile goal.